# Xpath запрос - настройка

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, htmlagilitypack

Xpath `//a[contains(text(),'mytext')]`

Консоль в chrome выдаёт что есть 100 элементов по такому `xpath`

А как мне обратиться по их номеру ?

- Так не выходит
  `//a[contains(text(),'mytext')][55]`

Как мне вытащить сначала `[55]`, затем `[67]` Например ?

Идут не друг за дружкой по иерархии, а разбросаны кто как.

Comment: Ваш `XPath` дает эти элементы в виде коллекции, ну так и работайте с этой коллекцией далее, аля `.SelectNodes("//a[contains(text,'mytext')]")[55]`, просто какой смысл в повторном поиске элементов? Ну а так, я вам советую найти что-то, что заменит индекс, ибо это ооочень нестабильное значение. По поводу `Так не выходит` - наверно потому, что `text`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Эммм, ошибка вышла с `text` xD, он со скобками - исправил. Если на `htmlagilitypack` мерить, то вот так `.SelectSingleNode("//a[contains(text(),'mytext')][55]")` не выходит вытащить элемент. Хотя в `.SelectNodes("//a[contains(text,'mytext')]")` их будет за 100 штук.

Comment: Вы уверены, что там индекс 55? Попробуйте 0, даст он `a` из списка или нет? Также попробуйте `.SelectSingleNode("//a[contains(text(),'mytext')]")`  (без каких либо индексов, взять один объект), будет результат?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ без индексов будет

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вот в том то и дело, что в `консоли chrome` при поиске мне показывает за `100+ `элементов. Но по индексу они все не более `[1]`. В то время как `.SelectNodes("//a[contains(text,'mytext')]")` их вытащит все и тогда я уже смогу обратиться по индексу htmlNodes[55]

Comment: Ну тогда я без понятия что у вас там, надо смотреть ваш код и ваш HTML, без этого проблему не воспроизвести. Вон даже набросал [пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5nOzmp), который имеет вашу XPath и все как видите работает. Делайте минимальный воспроизводящий пример. P.S. Метку C# наверно накинуть не помешало бы?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Обновил пример https://dotnetfiddle.net/48l1zN

Comment: Ок, теперь понял проблему вашу. Но тогда почему нельзя просто `.SelectNodes("//a[contains(text(),'Некий текст')]")[1]`? Ну а если через XPath, то тогда оберните условие в круглые скобки и уже после через индекс (`(//a[contains(text(),'Некий текст')])[2]`), [пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mm5i5U).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, я по сути и сделал через `.SelectNodes`, но не давало покоя как это делать с помощью `XPath`, так как сначала пошёл по этому пути. `()` то что нужно, спасибо.